# MSSQL based bar and line graph

Tags: php, sql-server, asp-classic, graph, charts

i am not familiar with ASP or PHP writing, i am database admin only capable to do simple code changes.

Trying to find any usable/workable copy/paste sample of graph/chart for visulazation of simple two column MSSQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Free ones: [Open flash chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/), [php-gnuplot](http://php-gnuplot.sourceforge.net/), [pchart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/), [xml/swf charts](http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/index.php), [Visualize](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/), [igrapher](http://igrapher.com/#), [awesomeJS](http://cyberpython.github.com/AwesomeChartJS/)

Semi commercial: [rgraph](http://www.rgraph.net/), [amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com/), [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/),

and many, many more...

Comment: Anyone with sample open flash chart connected into MSSQL ??

Comment: Yes, all of them if you write an adapter in ASP, Perl, PHP, Java... It would be really stupid to expose your DB server directly on the internet (which would be a pre-requisite for generating graphs on the client).

Answer (score 0):

For graphing, the easiest way is to use the [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/). A good introduction is here: [Quick-Start Guide for Google Charts API](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/quick-start-guide-for-google-charts-api)

For accesses the data in the database, it depends on how your server is set up as to what is easiest. I would use PHP and install it from Microsoft's [PHP on Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx) page. Make sure you use the PHP [SqlSrv](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/) driver for PHP. Brian Swann's [Accessing SQL Server Databases with PHP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc793139%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) looks like a good place to start.

Alternatively, use ASP.NET, but I can't help you. [Intro to SQL Server with ASP.NET](http://www.kirupa.com/net/sql_asp_introduction.htm) looks like a reasonable place to start though.

If it's a one-off graph you are creating, then you could always export the data to CSV via the SQL Server admin tools and then graph in Excel.